# Consistency in the help menu

Tags: discussion, top-bar, help, user-experience

In the main sites, the help menu looks like this:

[image: Normal menu]

However, when we get to Meta, the menu turns into this:

[image: Meta Menu]

The "Back to (Main Site)" link is on the top, and we have four menu items now.

My first point is that "Back to (Main Site)" should be in the same position as the "Meta" link the original menu. That way, when I click on the link for Meta, I can return to the main site the same way I came.

Additionally, to make it "three and three", the Tour link probably doesn't need to be in the help menu for meta. Instead, "What's Meta" should use that spot, as we all know Meta is Different.

Mockup:

[image: Combined mockup]

Comment: **+1** Also note that `meta.[site]/tour` redirects to `[site]/help`, making the meta tour link even more unnecessary.